# How to speed up searching in List<string> with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

> yes, I search any name/surname/patronymic starts with "jo"

Taking regex out might simplify that. If we upgrade FullName with a method that returns true if any of the names it knows start with any of the prefixes it is given:

```
public struct FullName
{
    public string Name;
    public string Surname;
    public string Patronymic;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var str = string.Join(' ', Surname?.Trim(), Name?.Trim(), Patronymic?.Trim()).Trim();
        return str;
    }
}
```

And we then use it to filter the list:

```
//speed - 65902
public List<string> Search(string prefix)
{
    var items = _fullNames.ToArray();
    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(prefix))
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    if (prefix.Length > 100)
        throw new ArgumentException();


    for(int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((items[i].Surname != null | items[i].Name != null | items[i].Patronymic != null) && items[i].ToString().Contains(prefix))
            result.Add(items[i].ToString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

I moved some of your code around - better to check input is null before you split it than after..

Comment: How many names (+/-) are there in the list? How long takes currently?

Comment: using a lambda like List.Where(..) instead a foreach and crate a new list

Comment: @spzvtbg I don't know, but test say 'Too long search nanoSeconds=558563'

Comment: @J.Salas it's faster but not enough (513208 nanosec)

Comment: What kind of searches do you need to make? Are you looking for anyone whose any-name starts with "jo" followed by any letter, or anyone who has "jo" anywhere in a name ? It seems simpler to just do a string search and look at the index and length of the result

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, I search any name/surname/patronymic starts with "jo"

Comment: That doesn't need regex

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, I change my code to `Linq` query and it working faster (93600 nanosec), but it's too long.

Comment: How many nanoseconds is acceptable? How many names and prefixes have you got?

Comment: I don't know, I have only task.

Comment: If you don't know how fast it has to be, how will you know when you are finished?

Comment: @Neil when the test turns green

Comment: OK, so the test must contain the target speed.   How fast does the code need to run?

Comment: @Neil I don't know, but it could be <50000 ns, current - 66539 ns)

Comment: Just run it on a faster PC !  Do you not have access to the test code?  Why can't you see what the test requirements are?

Comment: @Neil I post answer from this question later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a TrieNode (prefix tree) for search by prefix:

```
public class TrieNode
{
    private FullName? _data;
    private Dictionary<char, TrieNode> _children = new Dictionary<char, TrieNode>();
    public void Add(string path, FullName data)
    {
        if (path == null)
            return;
        Add(path, 0, data);
    }

    private void Add(string path, int index, FullName data)
    {
        if (index == path.Length)
        {
            _data = data;
            return;
        }

        var c = path[index];
        if (!_children.ContainsKey(c)) 
            _children.Add(c, new TrieNode());
        _children[c].Add(path, index + 1, data);
    }

    public void GetByPrefix(string prefix, HashSet<FullName> result)
    {
        GetByPrefix(prefix, 0, result);
    }

    private void GetByPrefix(string prefix, int index, HashSet<FullName> result)
    {
        if(_data.HasValue)
            result.Add(_data.Value);

        if (index >= prefix.Length)
        {
            foreach (var node in _children.Values)
                node.GetByPrefix(prefix, index, result);
        }
        else
        {
            var c = prefix[index];
            if (_children.ContainsKey(c))
                _children[c].GetByPrefix(prefix, index + 1, result);
        }
    }
}
```

overriding methods in struct

```
public struct FullName
{
    public string Name;
    public string Surname;
    public string Patronymic;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var str = (Surname?.Trim() + " " + Name?.Trim() + " " + Patronymic?.Trim()).Trim();
        return str;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is FullName name
        && Name == name.Name
        && Surname == name.Surname
        && Patronymic == name.Patronymic;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 17;
        if (Name != null)
            hash = hash * 23 + Name.GetHashCode();
        if (Surname != null)
            hash = hash * 23 + Surname.GetHashCode();
        if (Patronymic != null)
            hash = hash * 23 + Patronymic.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

and write search method:

```
public List<string> Search(string prefix)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(prefix))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Аргумент не может быть пустым");

    if (prefix.Length > 100)
        throw new ArgumentException("Длина аргумента не может привышать 100 символов.");
    
    var set = new HashSet<FullName>();
    _trie.GetByPrefix(prefix, set);

    return set.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> yes, I search any name/surname/patronymic starts with "jo"

Taking regex out might simplify that. If we upgrade FullName with a method that returns true if any of the names it knows start with any of the prefixes it is given:

```
public class FullName
{
    private string[] _names = new string[3];

    public string Name { get => _names[0]; set => _names[0] = value?.Trim(); }
    public string Surname { get => _names[1]; set => _names[1] = value?.Trim(); }
    public string Patronymic { get => _names[2]; set => _names[2] = value?.Trim(); }

        
    public string GetPersonalDataAsString()
    {
        var str = string.Join(' ', Surname, Name, Patronymic).Trim();
        return str;
    }
    public bool AnyStartsWithAny(string[] prefixes){
        return _names.Any(n => prefixes.Any(p => n?.StartsWith(p, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ?? false));
    }
}
```

And we then use it to filter the list:

```
public List<string> Search(string prefixStr)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefixStr))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(prefixStr));

    var prefixes = prefixStr.Split();

    if (prefixes.Length > 100)
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot supply more than 100 prefixes; be more decisive");

    return _fullnames.Where(fn => fn.AnyStartsWithAny(prefixes)).ToList();

}
```

I moved some of your code around - better to check input is null before you split it than after..

Comment: I can't do it: `string[] _names = new string[3]`. 
Error CS8400 Feature 'parameterless struct constructors' is not available in C# 8.0. Please use language version 10.0 or greater. I have .NET 3.1

Comment: `struct` -> `class`

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need to perform a `StartsWith`, you do not need regex. Instead, you can do something of the like of

```
.Any(f => (f != null) && f.StartsWith(prefix))
```

for your checking. If you use a database, then it is highly advisable that you `index` your `table` by your sort criteria, that would boost up speed for real.

If this is not in a database, then, instead of an array as data-structure, you could have a tree, of which each node is a letter. So, if you search for `jo`, then you would find the child in the root whose value is `j` and then find the child of `j` whose value is `o` and then flatten its subtree to get the results.